# PHP variable scope issue inside of array_filter

Tags: php, variables, scope

I come from a JS world and have trouble understanding this piece of code:

```
function getCountryName($code, $codes){
  print_r($code);

  array_filter(
    $codes,
    function ($e) {
      if($e->cca2 == $code){
        print_r($e->name->common);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

The second line is for debug only and it prints given $code. But here: `if($e->cca2 == $code){` $code seems to be undefined. How is it even possible? It works with `$GLOBALS['code']` but I don't want to use globals. How come array_filter has no access to it's own scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use 'use'.

```
function getCountryName($code, $codes){
  print_r($code);

  array_filter(
    $codes,
    function ($e) use($code) {
      if($e->cca2 == $code){
        print_r($e->name->common);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`$code` is in `getCountryName()`’s scope. You then have a callback for `array_filter()`, which is an anonymous function and has its own scope. To access the variable, you need to [`use`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) it, which will make the callback inherit the variable from its parent scope (the function):

```
function getCountryName($code, $codes){
print_r($code);
 array_filter(
    $codes,
    function ($e) use ($code) {
      if($e->cca2 == $code){
        print_r($e->name->common);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `function()` creates its own scope. If you want to pass a variable from the outside into the inner scope, you can use `use`:

```
array_filter(
  $codes,
  function ($e) use ($code) {
    if($e->cca2 == $code){
      print_r($e->name->common);
    }
  }
);
```

This way the use of the variable from the outside scope is explicit.